# Galvanic isolation in multiple battery design

Tags: batteries, motor, noise, isolation

I'm trying to design a board to control a couple of DC motors (or stepper motors) for a small robot. The device will integrate a control logic based on a uC and the necessary H bridges for the motors. DC motors speed will be modulated with ~1 kHz PWM signals.
No great powers involved: logic is powered at 3.3 V while motors work at 12 V maximum (haven't decided yet, may be 5 V too) with a current draw limited to 3 A.

The goal is to integrate batteries and their charge circuitry as well. Li-Ion cells will be used, along with DCDC converters to generate the required voltages.
I've used the plural because I'm planning on use two different batteries: one dedicated on the control logic section and the other for the motors and the H bridges (power section). I had some past experiences with disturbances and voltage drops when using a single battery to power both sections, so I'd like to separate the two power supplies in order to avoid any future issues. However, I recognize that these experiences may be caused by a poor circuit design.

And here comes the questions: does it really makes sense to use two different batteries or it is sufficient to design an effective ground path and to use bypass capacitors, taking into account the low currents and voltages involved?
Moreover, if using two batteries is a good idea, is it worthed to galvanically isolate the two sections to completely avoid ground loops and disturbances propagations? Or, again, a good ground path design on the PCB is enough?

If more details are required, I can add them.
Sorry if I made some grammar errors, English is not my mother tongue.

Comment: english is better than fine

Comment: You could isolate the power section - gate drivers and current/voltage measurements, but the price is high and probably not needed for such small motor.  Do you have any schematics of your motor power stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no pointing isolating the batteries unless all your circuits are isolated between the two sides as well. ie. Control board running off battery A and motor driver running off battery B must interface through isolators. Or motor driver that accepts battery A for logic power and battery B for motor power must have isolators on board between the two sides. Isolation takes a LOT of work because of this.

Two unisolated batteries (i.e. sharing a ground) does help with power supply disturbance issues but won't really help with noise issues like isolated batteries will.  Often a single battery with proper decoupling and grounding is the simpler solution for both.

Two batteries (isolated or not) makes sense if your motors run at much higher voltage than your logic because you do not need to step down the voltage. It also allows your motors to run the battery dry but not kill your electronics which can be important in some applications (i.e. a model airplane whose propeller motor uses one battery but the electronics  which include the radio and servo motors which allow you to control the plane run off another battery).

Newbies worry too much about ground loops. Ground loops are only a problem if they cause a problem.

On a tiny 3A robot there should be no good reason to isolate or use two batteries. 50A airplanes often fly with single batteries and no isolation, and those things crash with too much noise or power supply disturbances.

DO NOT regulate the voltage to the motor. Choose the motor and batteries to run direct. It is a waste to try and regulate voltage for high a power system that is not sensitive to voltage like a motor. A motor driver is kind of like a crude regulator for the motor and that is its job so don't make yourself do the same thing twice.